# Why does my glass fishbowl have a gray sphere inside it, even without an object there?

Tags: rendering, glass

[image: The rendering of my bowl had this weird sphere around it.]

I can clearly see a grey sphere looking thing that doesn't exactly look like a glass bowl. [Here's the blender file for the bowl.](https://www.mediafire.com/file/vi4ejipgcpiu0vq/glass%20bowl.blend)

I have no idea what is causing this.

Comment: I think that is the reflection of itself. See the small white dot in the black area of the bowl (Upper right). There is an opposite white dot in the grey sphere (Lower left).

Comment: There's a little more wrong than just the normals.  The table plane intersects the bowl, your light bounces are all set to 128 (which will greatly increase render time), the Transparent shader has a gray color (must be white to actually be transparent), the sun is too bright, and, as is, you're shader nodes will not allow the bowl to cast a shadow (not realistic).

Comment: @bertmoog How would I allow the bowl to cast a shadow?

Comment: You can add a multiply node to adjust the amount of shadow that's cast.  See this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/86695/38953

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your faces are flipped inside out. Select all faces and press Ctrl+N, to correct this. Additionally, you have double vertices. Select all vertices in your mesh, and in the toolbox to the left click 'remove doubles'.

Comment: You're welcome. So please accept this answer as the correct one to mark this problem as solved.